# minikube kernel: hpet1: lost 319 rtc interrupts

Tags: minikube

$ minikube ssh
$ journalctl -f

```
Aug 02 04:25:38 minikube kernel: hpet1: lost 319 rtc interrupts
Aug 02 04:25:43 minikube kernel: hpet1: lost 318 rtc interrupts
Aug 02 04:25:48 minikube kernel: hpet1: lost 317 rtc interrupts
Aug 02 04:25:53 minikube kernel: hpet1: lost 319 rtc interrupts
Aug 02 04:25:58 minikube kernel: hpet1: lost 318 rtc interrupts
...
```

minikube has a slightly higher CPU footprint. When I check the log, I get a lot of such records. What does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

This alert is related to the virtual HW clocking mechanism and is rather a harmless one.

You need to set the boot parameter `hpet=disable`

Detailed solution can be found [here](https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/ACPI_Wakeup#HPET_conflict).

1. Go to `/etc/default/grub`
2. Find the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"`
3. Add: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet hpet=disable"` parameter behind the existing separated with a space
4. Save the file
5. Update grub with: `sudo update-grub`
6. Reboot

Also, this log message is generated if you have the plugin `Scheduled Wakealarms` installed.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: `cat: /etc/default/grub: No such file or directory` It seems that there is no such file in minikube

Comment: Look at [this cheatsheet](https://cheatsheet.dennyzhang.com/cheatsheet-minikube-a4). You will find the location of Minikube config folders. There look for the hpet="on" option and change it to "off"